# How to properly enable/ disable ion-refresher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-v1

```
<ion-refresher pulling-text = "{{'RefreshingText' | translate}}"
               on-refresh="doRefresh()"
               ng-if = "scroll.scrollCssValue == 'hidden'">
```

The above code works perfectly according to my requirement. Only problem is I am getting console warning.

The above code give me console warning.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
>       at ionic.bundle.js:60346
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at overscroll (ionic.bundle.js:60322)
>       at scroll (ionic.bundle.js:60399)

How can I do properly enable/disable the ion-refresher?

Comment: The `ng-if` directive is AngularJS syntax but the question is tagged for Angular 2+ *ngIf. Is this an Ionic V1 question or an Angular 2+ Ionic question?

Comment: No its tagged as angularjs. I have deleted the ng-if section. Thank you so much for correction.